# r packages to read SPSS zcompressed files

Tags: r, statistics, large-files, spss

I have recently discovered the .zsav extension, which was a heaven-sent, as I have SPSS .sav files in my network that range from 4-10GB in size, but when saving them as .zsav they reduce to approximately 300-500MB.
Having said that, i'm finding it difficult to find a way to read these formats in R.
Does anyone know of any packages for R that would allow the use of this format, or any R code that could read it/workarounds?

Comment: someone has asked for this in the `haven` package without success: https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/153

Comment: hi, yeah i noticed after posting - but being it was over 18 months ago i was hoping there'd have been some development..?